# Generate uique url of form results

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, url, unique

I currently use a form to get wordpress posts according to the users selections of choices in a form.

After submitting the form you get a series of results or not depending on the choices.

I would like to generate a unique page link/url of these results.

So I had the following in mind:

```
page-result?posts-id=12,22,35&day=0&day2=1
```

`posts-id` are the ids of the posts in the results. and day tells if the day is hidden or visible.

Now my form uses post and I know that with get you get something similar but that is of the form selections and I need to make an url of the results.

What is the best way to do this.

If needed I can add the code I use at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How users make selections? Checkboxes? Proceed this way:

```
// Anyway user make choices, you can create an 
// array of choosen post IDs, right?
$post_ids = array();
$post_ids[] = 12;
$post_ids[] = 22;
$post_ids[] = 35;

// Then you jave something to get choosen "day"
$day = 0;
$day2 = 1;

// Now build your new URL
$post_ids = implode(',', $post_ids);
$url = "page-result?posts-id=$post_ids&day=$day&day2=$day2";

// And redirect user to that URL
header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

Comment: First there is a radio button form which gets posted to a second form with checkboxes. after that form is posted you get the results shown. These results need to get an unique url. Can I just add the post id's to the url to get it to work or do I need to do more?

Comment: You, sure you can. Is what I tell you in my answer. On the `page-result` page then you must do something to read IDs coming from `explode(',', $_GET['posts-id'])`. You get it?